# Force Windows 10 to refresh device driver (Microsoft LifeCam) from update server?

Tags: windows-10, drivers

Just pulled what was a working "Microsoft LifeCam Studio" out of the draw and tried to use it and the drivers are broken "This device is not configured correctly. (Code 1)".
Attempts to update the driver gives "One of the installers for this device cannot perform the installation at this time."

Normally the next step would be "Uninstall Device" along with "Delete the driver software for this device" but since it is a Microsoft driver there is no option to delete the driver, consequently the next time the camera is plugged in the same baulked drivers are started...

What I'm after is a way to force the system to treat the camera as an unrecognized device and redownload whatever the freshest (or a previous version) drivers are for the device from the Microsoft servers.

Comment: Are you sure a more up-to-date driver even exists? I think this is highly unlikely for a device that old.

Comment: Do you know the camera actually works?   I have a Microsoft Life Cam on my Windows 11 desktop.  It is not new (probably within 5 years) and it works just fine with Microsoft Drivers.

Comment: Do you have a backup of your computer that you can restore it from completely? If so, maybe, just maybe, [This device is not configured correctly. (Code 1)__](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/this-device-is-not-configured-correctly-code-1/3926fecc-0f2a-4533-8da7-6ab329aad4b0) will help. If it does, you could write your own answer here (citing the article that helped, of course).